# Stuck in "ora-01861 literal does not match format string"

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is my query:

```
SELECT A.WEEK, B.NAME, A.GENDER
 FROM TABLE A, TABLE2 B
 WHERE A.WEEK BETWEEN TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('2013051'), 'yyyymmw')
             AND TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('2013063'), 'yyyymmw')
  AND A.WEEK = B.WEEK;
```

In both table, data in WEEK column is recorded as '2013051' as 1st week of May, or '2013063' as 3rd week of JUNE. And all the other data in WEEK column is recorded in a same format, consisted of 7 characters. The last letter stands for the number of week it is belong.

When I run this query, it shows

ora-01861 literal does not match format string

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What SQL are using?  Oracle, I assume?

Comment: I added the Oracle tag to your question - it's generally a good idea to specify which flavor of SQL you are using, as there differences in the various implementations.

Comment: If `WEEK` column is varchar, then why convert the value to date and back to varchar? Won't it be sufficient to use `a.week between '2013051' and '2013063'`

Comment: Also, `TO_DATE ('2013051', 'yyyymmw')` gives me `ORA-01820: format code cannot appear in date input format`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your brackets are incorrect.

```
SELECT A.WEEK, B.NAME, A.GENDER
 FROM TABLE A, TABLE2 B
 WHERE A.WEEK BETWEEN TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('2013051', 'yyyymmw'))
             AND TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('2013063', 'yyyymmw'))
  AND A.WEEK = B.WEEK;
```

The TO_DATE functions needs two arguments - the string to convert, and the formatstring.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an oracle to test it here but checking the TO_DATE documentation it seems you are missing the format on it. Here is how I would try the conversions:

```
WHERE A.WEEK BETWEEN TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('2013051','yyyymmw'))
             AND TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('2013063', 'yyyymmw'))
```

Here is the two links I've checked:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Hope it helps.